# Counting all characters except space in the using the ls|wc-c?

Tags: linux, shell, ls, wc, one-liner

Suppose running `ls` command gives the following output on the terminal:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt '4 b'
```

*['4 b' is the name of a folder]*

When I run `ls | wc -c` at the same location, I get 18, which is because it considers space as a character. What should I do to avoid counting spaces as characters(even the spaces within the filenames)?

Comment: Running `ls` when the output is *not* a terminal (eg, when using a pipe like this) is equivalent to running `ls -1` -- it prints each file on a line by itself, separated by newlines.  You need `ls -C` to force listing in columns like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete all spaces:

```
ls | tr -d ' ' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` to remove the spaces:

```
ls | tr -d ' ' | wc -c
```